# Node.js Sharp [Error: Input file contains unsupported image format] while using png

Tags: node.js, sharp

I'm trying to build a social media network and for uploading pfp's I'm trying to make them a square using sharp. The error code I get when I catch the error is: `[Error: Input file contains unsupported image format]`

Here is my code

```
image.mv(__dirname + "/upload/" + image.name);

  var imput = __dirname + "/upload/" + image.name;
  try {
    await sharp(imput)
      .extract({ width: 300, height: 300, left: 50, top: 70 })
      .toFile(__dirname + "/upload/" + "pfp3.png");
  } catch (error) {

    console.log(error);
  }
  // Move the uploaded image to our upload folder

  // All good
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

The image I upload is a png and I would expect that to be a supported file type, I also tried a jpg and a jpeg (I know thats the same but I still wanted to try just in case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found pout what the problem was, it didn't wait correctly for the upload of the image this line solved it:

```
  await image.mv(__dirname + "/upload/" + image.name);
```